# Logging into a website with jsoup

Tags: java, networking, jsoup

I am trying to login to my college website using jsoup using the following code:

```
public class captcha {
 public Map cookies;
 private String regno = "####"; //my regno
 private String passwd = "####"; //my pass

 public HashMap<String,String> downloadCaptcha()throws Exception {
    Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://academicscc.vit.ac.in/student/stud_login.asp")
            .timeout(300000)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();

    cookies = response.cookies();
    Document doc = response.parse();
    Elements fields = doc.select("form input");
    HashMap<String,String> formFields = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (Element field : fields ){
        formFields.put(field.attr("name"), field.attr("value"));
    }

    Connection.Response resultImageResponse = Jsoup.connect("https://academicscc.vit.ac.in/student/captcha.asp")
            .cookies(cookies)
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .method(Connection.Method.GET).timeout(30000).execute();


    cookies.putAll(resultImageResponse.cookies());

    FileOutputStream out = (new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File("abc.jpg")));
    out.write(resultImageResponse.bodyAsBytes());
    out.close();

    System.out.println("Captcha Fetched");
    //formFields.remove("message");
    formFields.values().remove("Forgot Password ?");

    System.out.println(formFields);


    return formFields;
}

public void getData(HashMap<String, String> formFields) throws Exception{
    Connection conn = Jsoup.connect("https://academicscc.vit.ac.in/student/stud_login.asp")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0")
            .cookies(cookies)
            .timeout(0)
            .data(formFields)
            .method(Connection.Method.POST);



    Connection.Response response = conn.execute();
    cookies = response.cookies();
    System.out.println(response.cookies());
    Document doc= response.parse();
    FileWriter fr = new FileWriter("response.html");
    PrintWriter pw= new PrintWriter(fr);
    pw.println(doc.toString());
    System.out.println(doc.toString());
    pw.close();
    fr.close();
}

private void run() throws Exception, IOException {
    HashMap<String, String> formFields = downloadCaptcha();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String vrfcd = br.readLine();

    formFields.put("regno", regno);
    formFields.put("passwd", passwd);
    formFields.put("vrfcd", vrfcd);
    System.out.println(formFields);
    getData(formFields);

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    captcha main = new captcha();
    main.run();
   }
}
```

I get the captcha and get the cookies. Then i get form fields. Then i input the captcha and set its value into form fields in addition to reg no and password. Then i connect and get a response. 
The problem is that i get back the login page as response.

Any help appreciated :)

**EDIT**: While logging in with chrome i get REQUEST COOKIES

```
SESSIONIDSGASBSQA = DKCNGAHAAGPJILOAHBGEPDHO                    
_ga =GA1.3.1284394013.1479732373                    
 logstudregno=
```

While the code output has request cookies as

```
{logstudregno=, ASPSESSIONIDSGASBSQA=JODNGAHAIIGMCJALLNMOHKMG}
```

Comment: You have another field called "message" which you ignore.

Comment: I checked the network activity in chrome while logging in and got the form data.
     _message:_
     _regno:#### (my reg)_
     _passwd:#### (my pass)_
     _vrfcd:FRH6B7_
As you can see message field is empty.

Comment: It doesn't mean that you can ignore it.

Comment: So what do i do with it? Earlier i had removed it from formField but i commented that line out. 
Also EDIT: The code includes _println(Response.cookies())_
The output of this is _logstudregno=_ ( null). 
And on chrome i checked the cookies and it is
_logstudregno=####_ (my reg no)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of headache i have finally solved it. Turns out i was simply not using the correct url for post. I checked in Chrome and found the actual url. Now it works :).

```
public void getData(HashMap<String, String> formFields) throws Exception{
         Connection conn = Jsoup.connect("https://academicscc.vit.ac.in/student/stud_login_submit.asp")
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0")
        .cookies(cookies)
        .timeout(0)
        .data(formFields)
        .method(Connection.Method.POST);}
```

Still am curious to know about why i get more cookies using Chrome.